# how does nginx determine the content-type header?

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

[image]

I have a react application behind 3 nginx proxy, and when a js file is loaded with the browser it has a wrong content-type header, which is `text/html` instead of `application/javascript`; this cause the application not working and in the browser console an error is displayed, complaining that the file has a wrong MIME type.

My 3 nginx proxy works in this way. The first nginx proxy forward requests of the form `/demo/...` to the local port 7000. On this port a containerized nginx dispatch request to other containers based on the value of the second and third segment of the request uri. The third containerized nginx just serve static content.

**Configuration of the first nginx proxy**

position: /etc/nginx/site-available/default

nginx version: 1.14.2

```
server {
        server_name ...;

        location /demo {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000;
        }
...
}
```

**Configuration of the second nginx proxy (containerized, dispatch requests to other containers)**

position: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

nginx version: 1.20.1

```
server {

    listen 80;
    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    location ~* ^/demo/([^/]+)/api/(.*) {
        set $demo_backend ctn_backend_$1;
        proxy_pass http://$demo_backend/api/$2$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* ^/demo/([^/]+)/(.*) {
        set $demo_frontend ctn_frontend_$1;
        proxy_pass http://$demo_frontend/$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200 'the demo is not ready found or it is expired :(';
    }
}
```

**Configuration of the third nginx proxy (containerized, serve static content)**

position: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

nginx version: 1.20.1

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

The containers are based on the image `nginx:stable-alpine`.

The first nginx serves also local js files, and the files loaded have the correct content-type `application/javascript`.

When I tried this 'system' locally the situation is different because I'm on windows 10 and I don't need the first nginx proxy so there isn't here but I don't have this kind of problem. By the way after further investigating there is something strange happening (keep in mind that there only 2 layer locally): if I make a curl request from inside the last nginx container to a js file the content-type is wrong (`text/html`), but if I make a request from the previous container (the dispatcher) the content-type is correct, `application/javascript`. This behaviour doesn't repeat in the test environment.

I checked the file mime.type on all three nginx hosts and it seems ok because the entry `application/javascript js;` is listed.

So I'm wondering how the content-type is determined and what could I check.

Comment: It is determined by the name of the file actually returned. The `try_files` statement in your last configuration will return the requested file if it exists, otherwise `index.html` is returned, and that file has a MIME type of `text/html`.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the problem and you are right. The file returned is always the index.html... This was the first thing to I should had to check instead of searching in other places.